# Can't navigate to the Custom Self REgistration page in Napili template?

Tags: community, community-builder, napili

I have create a lightning page for the self registration in the Napili template, And I have set the self registration page in the Napili template administration setup. But Once I'm navigating to that page it will automatically redirect to the login page, I have created a custom apex controller and already given the access for the guest user.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue. The issue is I have not set the community page as a public page in the Napili template administration setup.